# Identify Visually Similar Strings in Python

Tags: python, filter

I am working on a python project in which I need to filter profane words, and I already have a filter in place. The only problem is that if a user switches a character with a visually similar character (e.g. `hello` and `h311o`), the filter does not pick it up. Is there some way that I could find detect these words without hard coding every combination in?

Comment: Perhaps a Naive Bayes approach?

Comment: You could try OCR using tesseract, or similar.

Comment: Sooner or later, crude people find a way to defeat any filter. Such filters have the unintended consequence of making such people more annoying than before since they adopt more annoying misspellings.

Comment: `if word.replace("3", "e").replace("1", "l").replace("0", "o") in forbidden_words:`?

Comment: I'd use a dictionary or list of common variants (`"sh1t"`, etc.) which you could persist as a plain text file or json etc., and read in to memory. This would allow you to add new entries as needed, independently of the code itself. If you're only concerned about profanities, then the list should be reasonably small to maintain, and new variations unlikely. I've used a hard-coded dict to represent statistical t-table (with 1500 key/value pairs) in the past, seems like your problem would not require nearly that many keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all who posted an answer to this question. More answers are welcome, as they may help others. I ended up going off of David Zemens' comment on the question.

> I'd use a dictionary or list of common variants ("sh1t", etc.) which you could persist as a plain text file or json etc., and read in to memory. This would allow you to add new entries as needed, independently of the code itself. If you're only concerned about profanities, then the list should be reasonably small to maintain, and new variations unlikely. I've used a hard-coded dict to represent statistical t-table (with 1500 key/value pairs) in the past, seems like your problem would not require nearly that many keys.

While this still means that all there word will be hard coded, it will allow me to update the list more easily.

Answer (score 1):

What about translating `l331sp33ch` to `leetspeech` and applying a simple levensthein distance? (you need to `pip install editdistance` first)

```
import editdistance
try:
    from string import maketrans # python 2
except:
    maketrans = str.maketrans # python 3

t = maketrans("01345", "oleas")
editdistance.eval("h3110".translate(t), 'hello')
```

results in `0`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe build a relationship between the visually similar characters and what they can represent i.e.

```
dict = {'3': 'e', '1': 'l', '0': 'o'} #etc....
```

and then you can use this to test against your database of forbidden words. 
e.g.

input:he11

if any of the characters have an entry in dict,

dict['h'] #not exist

dict['e'] #not exist

dict['1'] = 'l'

dict['1'] = 'l'

Put this together to form a word and then search your forbidden list. I don't know if this is the fastest way of doing it, but it is "a" way.

I'm interested to see what others come up with.

*disclaimer:  I've done a year or so of Perl and am starting out learning Python right now. When I get the time. Which is very hard to come by.

Answer (score 0):

**Linear Replacement**

You will want something adaptable to innovative orthographers.  For a start, pattern-match the alphabetic characters to your lexicon of banned words, using other characters as wild cards.  For instance, your example would get translated to "h...o", which you would match to your proposed taboo word, "hello".

Next, you would compare the non-alpha characters to a dictionary of substitutions, allowing common wild-card chars to stand for anything.  For instance, asterisk, hyphen, and period could stand for anything; '4' and '@' could stand for 'A', and so on.  However, you'll do this checking from the strength of the taboo word, not from generating all possibilities: the translation goes the other way.

You will have a little ambiguity, as some characters stand for multiple letters.  "@" can be used in place of 'O' of you're getting crafty.  Also note that not all the letters will be in your usual set: you'll want to deal with moentary symbols (Euro, Yen, and Pound are all derived from letters), as well as foreign letters that happen to resemble Latin letters.

**Multi-character replacements**

That handles only the words that have the same length as the taboo word.  Can you also handle abbreviations?  There are a lot of combinations of the form "h-bomb", where the banned word appears as the first letter only: the effect is profane, but the match is more difficult, especially where the 'b's are replaced with a scharfes-S (German), the 'm' with a Hebrew or Cryllic character, and the 'o' with anything round form the entire font.

**Context**

There is also the problem that some words are perfectly legitimate in one context, but profane in a slang context.  Are you also planning to match phrases, perhaps parsing a sentence for trigger words?

**Training a solution**

If you need a comprehensive solution, consider training a neural network with phrases and words you label as "okay" and "taboo", and let it run for a day.  This can take a lot of the adaptation work off your shoulders, and enhancing the model isn't a difficult problem: add your new differentiating text and continue the training from the point where you left off.